# How do I fix unexpected token error?

Tags: javascript, sql

```
const prefix = "s!";
var dailyCheck = sql.get(`SELECT daily FROM scores WHERE userId = "${msg.author.id}"`);


bot.on("message", function (msg) {
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase = prefix + "dailies") {
        var daily = dailies(msg);
        daily; }
    });
bot.on("message", function dailies(msg) {
    reset.setInterval(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        if (date.getHours() === 15 && date.getMinutes() === 0) {
            sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET daily = 0`);
        }
    }, 60000);
    sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, daily INTEGER, glimmer INTEGER, wr INTEGER, rotw INTEGER)").then() => { 
        if (!row) {
            // I get the error of unexpected token "." in the next line.
            sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, points INTEGER, level INTEGER)").then() => {
            sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, daily, points, wr, rotw) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [msg.author.id, 1, 200, 0, 0]);
            msg.channel.send('Thank you for joining Playing Destiny Fast! You have 200 glimmer available!');
        } else if (dailyCheck = 1) {
            msg.channel.send('You have already accepted your daily rewards! Come back after the daily reset (9am PST) to claim again.');
        } else {
            sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET glimmer = ${row.glimmer + 200}, daily = 1, WHERE userId = ${msg.author.id}`);
            msg.channel.send('${message.author.id} has claimed their 200 daily glimmer! Total: ${row.glimmer}');
        }
    });
});
```

Specifically, I'm recieving an "unexpected token ." error at `sql.run(CREATE...` Please let me know how to correct this.

Comment: Please do not add tags to your title in the future.  Tags go in the tags field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.then` on one of the `sql.run`'s wrongly.
You're doing `.then() => {` which is invalid as you're trying to create an arrow function at a place which you cannot.
Instead, it should be `.then(() => {` as that gives the arrow function to the `.then` method, and gets rid of the unexpected token error.

Fixed version (replace the block after `reset.setInterval` with this).

```
sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, daily INTEGER, glimmer INTEGER, wr INTEGER, rotw INTEGER)").then(() => { 
    if (!row) {
        // I get the error of unexpected token "." in the next line.
        sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, points INTEGER, level INTEGER)").then(() => { // this is where the issue was occurring
            sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, daily, points, wr, rotw) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [msg.author.id, 1, 200, 0, 0]);
            msg.channel.send('Thank you for joining Playing Destiny Fast! You have 200 glimmer available!');
        });
    } else if (dailyCheck = 1) {
        msg.channel.send('You have already accepted your daily rewards! Come back after the daily reset (9am PST) to claim again.');
    } else {
        sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET glimmer = ${row.glimmer + 200}, daily = 1, WHERE userId = ${msg.author.id}`);
        msg.channel.send('${message.author.id} has claimed their 200 daily glimmer! Total: ${row.glimmer}');
    }
});
```

I suggest using an IDE like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or anything else, which will (generally) show you were the errors are, and sometimes even help you fix them.

Comment: This fixed my previous problem but introduced a trow err. The code looks for a sqlite3 module but because I haven't installed sqlite3 nor do I wish to use it for this bot, it cannot find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MaverickRiver Ask a new question and state what library you're using.